# Segmentation fault when running c++ code

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

Some time ago, I asked a question on stack overflow on how to capture fast screenshots with c++ in linux. I compiled that code (shown below) with `g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x -o app 'pkg-config --cflags --libs openCV'`. It compiled successfully, however, when I try to run the program, it results in a segmentation fault. I'm quite new to c++ and openCV so I have genuinely no idea what to do. Is it an error with my code or something else?

I apologize if I missed a detail needed to solve this error, if I did, please let me know via a comment.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

void ImageFromDisplay(std::vector<uint8_t>& Pixels, int& Width, int& Height, int& BitsPerPixel)
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);

    Width = attributes.width;
    Height = attributes.height;

    XImage* img = XGetImage(display, root, 0, 0 , Width, Height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    BitsPerPixel = img->bits_per_pixel;
    Pixels.resize(((((Width * Height) + 31) & ~31) / 8) * Height);

    memcpy(&Pixels[0], img->data, Pixels.size());

    XFree(img);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}


int main()
{
    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;
    int Bpp = 0;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;

    ImageFromDisplay(Pixels, Width, Height, Bpp);

    if (Width && Height)
    {
        Mat img = Mat(Height, Width, Bpp > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &Pixels[0]); //Mat(Size(Height, Width), Bpp > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &Pixels[0]); 

        namedWindow("WindowTitle", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Display window", img);

        waitKey(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `Pixels` is not empty?

Comment: Use a debugger first, before asking here ...

Comment: Checking even a *few* of those functions for potential failure, along with assessing the data values the *successful* executions return, will probably pay big benefits. [Don't Break Commandment #6](http://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html)

Comment: Does `img->data` contain `Pixels.size()` worth of data? You should assert this.

Comment: In my experience using `~` on signed integers leads to trouble. What are you trying to do with `~31`?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are `width * height` pixels, and each pixel has `bits_per_pixel` bits. Then img->data contains `(width * height * bits_per_pixel) / CHAR_BIT` bytes.

But you are trying to read (approximately) `(width * height * height) / 8` out of the `img->data` which makes no sense.

Change it to `(width * height * bits_per_pixel) / CHAR_BIT`.